# PHP dates not quite working

Tags: php, apache, time, logical-operators

Using logical operators with php dates is not working entirely correctly. It is able to work out that 2016 is before 2017, but is unable to realise that the 1st is before the 4th in the current month.

I've noticed this sort of error for a while now: how best to fix and avoid it?

```
$date_extra_early = date("2017-01-1 07:30:00");
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
var_dump($today);
var_dump($date_extra_early);
if ($today>$date_extra_early)
                    echo("today is greater than date extra early\n");
else echo("today is less than date extra early\n");
```

Outputs

> string(19) "2017-01-04 14:50:32" string(18) "2017-01-1 07:30:00" today
>   is less than than date extra early

Comment: Have you tried it with a correct datetime value as input? `$date_extra_early = date("2017-01-01 07:30:00");`

Comment: @feeela Okay the leading zero made that logical statement work, but this isn't a mere typo. I've noticed really flaky reliability of dates. Times I've depended on it and it's fallen apart disastrously. Wondering if there is a way to help guarantee it will work as intended.

Comment: not able to test at the moment but try 
`if  ( strtotime("$today")  > strtotime("$date_extra_early"))  ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may compare DateTime objects in favor of strings (the latter are returned by `date()`). Logical operations as `==, <, >, <=, >=` do work like charm with DateTime objects. Additionally the DateTime constructor understands a lot of different input formats and would also have helped with the malformed input.

```
$earlydate = new DateTime('2017-01-1 07:30:00');
$today = new DateTime('now');

if($today > $earlydate)
    echo 'today is greater than date extra early';
else
    echo 'today is less than date extra early';
```

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: What's the difference between date and datetime?

Comment: This is the time when you should think to yourself, "I should consult the manual".

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify date in correct `datetime` format

```
$date_extra_early = date("2017-01-01 07:30:00");
                                //^missing a leading 0 here
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/h7GIzX)

Or you could covert your date to integer and the compare

```
if (strtotime($today)>strtotime($date_extra_early)) {
    echo("today is greater than date extra early\n");
} else { 
    echo("today is less than date extra early\n");
}
```

In both case it prints

> today is greater than date extra early

[demo](http://ideone.com/qRVDoB)

Comment: That's not correct, the first parameter for the `date()` function, is a format string. Without any format characters, the function does not do anything so it just outputs the input.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed have to use the correct format for date().
In this case you are missing the leading 0 in front of the 1 (day)

```
$date_extra_early = date("2017-01-01 07:30:00");
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
var_dump($today);
var_dump($date_extra_early);
if ($today>$date_extra_early)
  echo("today is greater than date extra early\n");
else 
  echo("today is less than date extra early\n");
```

Outputs:

```
string '2017-01-04 22:00:57' (length=19)
string '2017-01-01 07:30:00' (length=19)
today is greater than date extra early
```